# Is it possible to select more than one status in the WooCommerce API orders endpoint?

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am reading orders from a WooCommerce site with the REST API (v1, OAuth), filtering for order status:

```
http://mypage.com/wc-api/v1/orders?status=on-hold
```

Works fine.

Now I would like to filter for multiple statuses. Is this possible? Like:

```
http://mypage.com/wc-api/v1/orders?status=on-hold,pending
```

[This site](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/using-woocommerce-rest-api-orders-endpoint/) suggests so:

> You can retrieve orders with a specific status using the `?status` parameter, **using commas to separate multiple statuses**.

(I've already tried, but I was not able to build a valid `oauth_signature` with the comma, probably some kind of encoding issue. So before I keep trying, I would like to know if multiple statuses are possible in the first place.)

Comment: Out of my depth with the API unfortunately, but what if you [encode](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) the comma as `%2C`?

Comment: Why are you using v1 along with oAuth? v1 will eventually be removed so it'd be best to try building with v2 at this point. For security purposes, might also be a good idea to use SSL.

Comment: Also note the official documentation is here: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

Comment: @helgatheviking yes, already tried that, but no succes.

Comment: @MichaelT we'll switch to v2 in the future, but we need to support WooCommerce 2.1 for now. However I'll try if it works with v2! PS. we are also using https (if the client supports it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the reason for not being able to build a correct `oauth_signature`: the comma has to be double-encoded (see [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/friendship-lookup-throws-error-when-parameter-contains-comma-delimited-value/8253/3) for details).

Answer: **yes** - it is possible to select multiple statuses comma-delimited just like that:

```
http://mypage.com/wc-api/v1/orders?status=on-hold,pending
```

This works in `v1`, `v2` and `v3`.

Comment: Any idea how to do that with the new 2.6 API? It used to work for the 2.5 API but returns an error for 2.6...

Comment: with the new API this is no longer possible, see https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11676

Comment: oh, I just realized it was you that posted the issue :)

Comment: that is not worked for me :((  Error 400 : Invalid parameters : status for API v2

Comment: works with `v3` of the API, I've just tested